# How to send xml request in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I have this button in my application.

```
 <%= button_to t('.add_html'), :class => "line-item", :product => product.id %>
```

When someone click on the button I want following line of the create action of my controller to be executed.

```
format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item,
                                 :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
```

My controller create action
      def create
        @cart = current_cart
        product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

```
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to(store_url) }
        format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item,
                             :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.errors,
                             :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= button_to t('.add_html'), action: :create, format: :xml, :class => "line-item" %>
```

Comment: @user1478137, both should work.  I edited because I didn't want to make up `products_path` which I implied based on your `controller`.